# List to Dictionary - Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following `list`:

```
[{'ext': '193', 'value': 'Name1'},
 {'ext': '194', 'value': 'Name 2'},
 {'ext': '192', 'value': 'Name3'},
 {'ext': '195', 'value': 'Name4'}]
```

How to create a `dictionary` of this to look like the following:

```
{'193': 'Name1', '194': 'Name 2'}
```

etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [dictionary comprehension](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDQQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Flegacy.python.org%2Fdev%2Fpeps%2Fpep-0274%2F&ei=4oZ0VKmQHMWomgW10oHIBA&usg=AFQjCNEyzBDXrvFV2zIgQkiAMMl4whPVEQ&sig2=wWHkiOM8CFEfpv9Ic5adUw):

```
mappings = [
    {'ext': '193', 'value': 'Name1'},
    {'ext': '194', 'value': 'Name 2'},
    {'ext': '192', 'value': 'Name3'},
    {'ext': '195', 'value': 'Name4'},
]

{d['ext']: d['value'] for d in mappings}
# => {'195': 'Name4', '194': 'Name 2', '193': 'Name1', '192': 'Name3'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Build a list of tuples and convert them to a dict:

```
l = [{'ext': '193', 'value': 'Name1'},
     {'ext': '194', 'value': 'Name 2'},
     {'ext': '192', 'value': 'Name3'},
     {'ext': '195', 'value': 'Name4'}]
d = dict((i["ext"], i["value"]) for i in l)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'193': 'Name1', '194': 'Name 2', '195': 'Name4', '192': 'Name3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since list has collection of tuple, You can achieve the same in below way:

```
mappings
[{'ext': '193', 'value': 'Name1'}, {'ext': '194', 'value': 'Name 2'}, 
{'ext': '192', 'value': 'Name3'}, {'ext': '195', 'value': 'Name4'}]
dict={}
for i in mappings:
    dict[i["ext"]] = i["value"]

dict
{'195': 'Name4', '194': 'Name 2', '193': 'Name1', '192': 'Name3'}
```